# Why the AsQueryable following by Any leads to select without Where clasue?

Tags: c#, .net, sql, entity-framework, lambda

I am using Entity framework 4 and I have the following piece of code:

```
public decimal GetSchoolSuccessRate(EvaluationComparationFilter filter)
{
    return this.GetSuccessRate(x => x.TestCampaignId == filter.TestCampaignId &&
                      x.SubjectId == filter.SubjectId &&
                      x.SectionNo == 0, filter.CountSvp);
}


private decimal GetSuccessRate(Func<FinalResult_Base, bool> wherePredicate, bool countSvp)
{
    using (var db = new DataEntities())
    {
        IQueryable<FinalResult_Base> query = db
                  .FinalResult_Bases.Where(wherePredicate).AsQueryable();


        if (!countSvp)
            query = query.Where(x => x.SpecialNeeds == 0);


        query.Any();   //--HERE is created the SELECT with NO WHERE clause
        ....
    }
}
```

I don't understand why the resulting `SELECT` statmenet at line `query.Any()`  does not have any `WHERE` clause. Neither filter from `wherePredicate` nor `x.SpecialNeeds == 0` is applied.

Any idea?

UPDATE 1:
The problem seems to be the `wherePredicate`, which is of type Func not Expression. I will try to use Expression.

Comment: That sounds very odd. Why are you using `AsQueryable` anyway? I wouldn't have expected you to need to, given that you're using EF...

Comment: @Jon Well, I did not write the code to be honest, but I guess it is needed to build the query dynamically. For example to add the `x => x.SpecialNeeds == 0 condition`. Is that not correct?

Comment: IMO `db.FinalResult_Bases.Where(wherePredicate)` is already `IQueryable` so you don't need `.AsQueryable();`

Comment: Did you step through it with the debugger is countSvp `false`?

Comment: @Grumbler85 I have with tried with countSvp both true and false. No effect.

Comment: @MichalB. No it is not. When I remove the AsQueryable, the compiler complains as the reuslt is Enumerable.  The wherePredicate (as it is Func not Expression) causes using overloaded version of Where method which returns Enumerable. However, this might be the root of the problem.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try changing the `GetSuccessRate` method declaration to

```
private decimal GetSuccessRate(
    Expression<Func<FinalResult_Base, bool>> wherePredicate, bool countSvp)
```

The reason is that there are two `Where` extension methods inside: `Enumerable.Where` and `Queryable.Where` and they have different declarations:

```
public static IEnumerable<TSource> Where<TSource>(
    this IEnumerable<TSource> source, 
    Func<TSource, bool> predicate)
```

and

```
public static IQueryable<TSource> Where<TSource>(
    this IQueryable<TSource> source, 
    Expression<Func<TSource, bool>> predicate)
```

so one receives `Func<TSource, bool>` and another one `Expression<Func<TSource, bool>>`

After you change your declaration the `.AsQueryable()` call will not make any difference.

Comment: +1; I have been just writing the answer ot my own question with very similar content :). I have found out whats going on from these two SO questions: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2876616/returning-ienumerablet-vs-iqueryablet, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2664841/difference-between-expressionfunc-and-func

Comment: he he, the first question contains my answer in the bottom:)
I wish I had time to explain internal details why it happens, but hopefully I'll post it soon.